# Searching for list in list python

Tags: python, arraylist, computer-science

Let's say I have the following main_list that contains other small_lists:

```
main_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

I want to find the small_list knowing the index 0 and 1 of the small_lists. So for instance, how can I create a getlist() function such that:

```
getlist(4,5) = [4, 5, 6, 7]
getlist(0,1) = [0, 1, 2, 3]
getlist(5,5) = None
getlist(9,10) = None
```

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: This is too broad. How do you handle negative indices? How do you handle slices? Why do you specify the start in terms of the inner lists but the end - start in terms of the outer list?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to map your list to a dictionary, where the keys are set to what you wan't to retrieve by. This can be done quickly using list comprehension as per the example below.

```
>>> main_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]

>>> indexed_list = { (i[0], i[1]) : i for i in main_list }

>>> indexed_list.get( (0,1) )
[0, 1, 2, 3]

>>> indexed_list.get( (4,5) )
[4, 5, 6, 7]

>>> indexed_list.get( (5,5) )
None
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks! Didn't realize that dictionary keys could be defined as tuples.

Comment: Can be defined as anything, the true underlying key is the object hash of whatever entity your using.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird way of classifying your elements. There are more suitable way's of storing your data lice dictionaries.

```
main_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
def getlist(a,b):
    for sub_list in main_list:
        if [a,b] == sub_list[0:2]:
            return sub_list

>>> print (getlist(4,5))
>>> print (getlist(2,1))
[4, 5, 6, 7]
None
```

Comment: Theres a typo in 4th line, it should be `sub_list`

Answer (score 0):

Checking sliced list would work here, This also works if there are more than one matching list with starting indexes similar to argument.

```
>>> main_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
>>> def get_list(tup, list_group):
...     return [list_ for list_ in list_group if list_[:2] == list(tup)]
...
>>> print(get_list((0, 1), main_list))
[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> main_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [0, 1, 10, 7]]  # multiple occurence
>>> print(get_list((0, 1), main_list))
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 10, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should solve your problem, or at least get you on the right track. It is also available [here on OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BySuFTebQ) for further tinkering, if you need.

```
main_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]

def getlist(idx0, idx1):
    # Assumes there isn't a match, unless one is found
    target_list = None

    # Loops through the list of lists, checking for a match with the characters at index 0 and 1
    for sub_list in main_list:
        if idx0 == sub_list[0] and idx1 == sub_list[1]:
            target_list = sub_list

    # returns the target list (if it found) or None (if it isn't)
    return target_list

print(getlist(4,5))
>>[4, 5, 6, 7]
print(getlist(0,1))
>>[0, 1, 2, 3]
print(getlist(5,5))
>>None
print(getlist(9,10))
>>None
```